# Screen recording on mac with pyautogui

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

I was attempting to record my screen using `pyautogui`, on my mac.

When pressing the `shift`, `cmd`, and `5` keys altogether I'm able to start a screen recording. By the same intuition, I thought the following code would work.

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'cmd', '5')
```

Instead the code simply types a `%` on the screen.

What can I do to fix this? (macOS Mojave)

Thanks.

Comment: The keyword for the cmd key is "command", spelled out.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.